# select() isnt responding to writing on /dev/input/mice

Tags: linux, unix, io, linux-device-driver, device-driver

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [select() isn't responding to writing on /dev/input/mice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12632630/select-isnt-responding-to-writing-on-dev-input-mice)

I am writing a program which monitors through `select()` on keyboard and mouse device files. It waits for any write operation (this should happen when there is a keystroke or mouse movement) on those file and as soon as there is a write operation, some jobs are executed. But it is not working. The code is given below. Can someone help me?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/stat.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<linux/input.h>
#include<linux/uinput.h>
#include<sys/time.h>
#include<unistd.h>




void main()
{
    int mouse_fd,kbd_fd,fd_max;
    struct input_event ev;
    fd_set rfs,wfs;

    if((mouse_fd=open("/dev/input/event3",O_WRONLY))==-1)
            {
                printf("opening mouse device file has failed \n");
            }
    else
            {
                printf("opening mouse device file has been successfull \n");
            }
    if((kbd_fd=open("/dev/input/event2",O_WRONLY))==-1)
            {
                printf("opening keyboard device file has failed \n");
            }
    else
        {
            printf("opening keyboard device file has been successfull \n");
        }


    if(mouse_fd>kbd_fd)
        {
            fd_max=mouse_fd;
        }
    else
        {
         fd_max=kbd_fd;
        }

    while(1)
    {
         FD_ZERO(&rfs);
             FD_ZERO(&wfs);
             FD_SET(mouse_fd,&rfs);
             FD_SET(kbd_fd,&rfs);
             FD_SET(mouse_fd,&wfs);
             FD_SET(kbd_fd,&wfs);
                 select((fd_max+1),&rfs,NULL,NULL,NULL);

        if(FD_ISSET(mouse_fd,&rfs))
            {
                printf("test mouse \n");
            }
        if(FD_ISSET(kbd_fd,&rfs))
            {
                printf("test keyboard \n");
                }

   }
}
```

when I am executing the program it gives output like:

```
[root@localhost Project]# gcc select.c
[root@localhost Project]# ./a.out
opening mouse device file has been successfull 
opening keyboard device file has been successfull 
test keyboard 
test mouse 
test keyboard 
test mouse 
test keyboard 
test mouse 
test keyboard 
test mouse 
test keyboard 
test mouse
```

Though I am not pressing any key or moving the mouse.

Comment: You are opening input devices for writing, and you are waiting reading possibilities in select(). Maybe you should open those devices for reading?

Answer (score 0):

You are opening I think wrong files

/dev/input/event3 - keyboard events
/dev/input/event2 - mouse events

check with 
cat /dev/input/event3