# select() isn't responding to writing on /dev/input/mice

Tags: io, device, c, input

I am writing a program which monitors through `select()` on the keyboard and mouse device files. It waits for any write operation (this should happen when there is a keystroke or mouse movement) on those files and as soon as there is a write operation, some jobs are executed.

But it's not working. My code is given below.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/stat.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<linux/input.h>
#include<linux/uinput.h>
#include<sys/time.h>
#include<unistd.h>

void main()
{
    int mouse_fd,kbd_fd,fd_max;
    struct input_event ev;
    fd_set rfs,wfs;

    if((mouse_fd=open("/dev/input/event3",O_WRONLY))==-1)
            {
                printf("opening mouse device file has failed \n");
            }
    else
            {
                printf("opening mouse device file has been successfull \n");
            }
    if((kbd_fd=open("/dev/input/event2",O_WRONLY))==-1)
            {
                printf("opening keyboard device file has failed \n");
            }
    else
        {
            printf("opening keyboard device file has been successfull \n");
        }

    FD_ZERO(&rfs);
    FD_ZERO(&wfs);
    FD_SET(mouse_fd,&rfs);
    FD_SET(kbd_fd,&rfs);
    FD_SET(mouse_fd,&wfs);
    FD_SET(kbd_fd,&wfs);

    if(mouse_fd>kbd_fd)
        {
            fd_max=mouse_fd;
        }
    else
        {
         fd_max=kbd_fd;
        }

    while(1)
    {
        select((fd_max+1),&rfs,NULL,NULL,NULL);
        sleep(2);
        if(FD_ISSET(mouse_fd,&rfs))
            {
                printf("test mouse \n");
            }
        if(FD_ISSET(kbd_fd,&rfs))
            {
                printf("test keyboard \n");
            }
   }
}
```

When I execute the program it produces output like this,

```
[root@localhost Project]# gcc select.c
[root@localhost Project]# ./a.out
opening mouse device file has been successfull 
opening keyboard device file has been successfull 
test keyboard 
test keyboard 
test keyboard 
test keyboard 
test keyboard 
test keyboard 
test keyboard 
test keyboard 
test keyboard
```

even though I am not pressing any key. Also, the mouse device file is never selected by select(), even though there is a physical mouse movement.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

You need to reinitialize your fd sets before every `select` call.  So, the loop in your program would look like:

```
while(1)
{
    FD_ZERO(&rfs);
    FD_ZERO(&wfs);
    FD_SET(mouse_fd, &rfs);
    FD_SET(kbd_fd, &rfs);
    FD_SET(mouse_fd, &wfs);
    FD_SET(kbd_fd, &wfs);

    select((fd_max+1),&rfs,NULL,NULL,NULL);

    // proceed normally
}
```

Also, per [User1's comment on your same question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12619683/select-isnt-responding-to-writing-on-dev-input-mice#comment17015708_12619683), you need to open the devices for reading, because you are trying to read data from them:

```
// Open device for reading (do you mean to use "/dev/input/mice" here?)
if ((mouse_fd = open("/dev/input/event3", O_RDONLY)) == -1)
```

Linux includes a [select_tut(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/select_tut.2.html) tutorial manpage with explanations of how to use `select` and an example program which can be useful as a reference. "Select Law" #11 reminds you that you need to reinitialize your fd sets before each call to `select`.

Comment: Mrb, i was facing the same issue in one of my programs and your answer on this has been very helpful .

Comment: That, or just use `poll` which doesn't require reinitialization every time.

Comment: @ mrb....have just done what u suggested...1.reinitialisation of fd_set every time & 2.setting the perrmission of the mouse device file to be O-RDONLY